# store html form in session

Tags: php, session

Let's say, I have a form that generated via some PHP code:

```
function selop($options){
    foreach($options as $value=>$text){
            $option .= "<option value=".$value.">$text</option>";
    }
    return "<select>$option</select>";
}
$year = selop(range(1,date("Y"))); //2014 now
```

This form `$year` is being called on every pages. I'm a little worried about the performance. So I decide to store this form in a session variable, like this:

```
function selop($options){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['form_year'])){
        foreach($options as $value=>$text){
            $option .= "<option value=".$value.">$text</option>";
        }
        $_SESSION['form_year'] = $option;
    }
    return "<select>".$_SESSION['form_year']."</select>";
}
```

Is this a good idea? Or any better solution in this case?

Comment: why not create a php file with the form and include it whenever you need it?

Comment: *"I'm a little worried about the performance"* - Have you got anything to suggest this is slow? It doesn't look like a particularly taxing function to me.

Comment: you have it already in $_FORM variable... why should you duplicate values?

Comment: PHP is a beast and can run more complex functions at ease, dont over complicate yourself by storing this in session, since this involves less processing, use with out sessions. If you store this in session then it will be overhead when you have more active users in site, since it eats memory

Comment: It's gonna loop an array of over 2 thousand items. Is this still better than session storage? Thank you all.

Comment: your form has 2,000 elements? If you mean display the data use pagination. You don't want the form in session, you can create a static form or if it's dynamically created cache it. redis, memecache, or flat file cache it so you don't need to make a db call unless the form's elements are updated. If you use flat file base64 encode it and serialize it.